# how to change text color when clicked on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Note: I didn't wrote all of the web-page code so I'm not sure about what `pdiv` is,I just want to try if i can change this small issue [want to make text color change when clicked to indicate which section you're reading]

The section is like this:

[image]

and then when you clicked it will show all menu section:

[image]

```js
function menuShowPol(pdiv){
 
    if(document.getElementById('menu_pol_div'+pdiv).
                                      style.display=="none") { 
      document.getElementById('menu_pol_div'+pdiv)
                            .style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
      document.getElementById('menu_pol_div'+pdiv)
                                    .style.display = "none";
  }  
}
function changeColor(pdiv){
 {
     document.getElementById('menu_pol_div'+pdiv)
                        .style.color = "#ff0000"; // forecolor
     document.getElementById('menu_pol_div'+pdiv)
               .style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000"; // backcolor
}
```

```html
 if($showpol==1){
  $menutext .= "<div id=\"country_menu_report_name\"
                      onclick=\"menuShowPol('".$pol."');
                      changeColor('".$pol."'); return 
                                false;\">".$thispol."</div>\n";
```

is there anyway to make it by use only css?
or if it has to be java can you help me? thanks

Comment: Please change your php code to the output html so we could actually see the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can actually pass "this" to your events, which will give access directly to the element that was interacted with. Here is a low-tech version (as said by others, you should use css classes to pack different states of your divs).

notice the `onclick="changeColor(this)"` in the header divs. also, I linked country_menu_report_X to menu_pol_X, which is not the best of practice, but hey, it works, and it's vanilla.

```js
function changeColor(pdiv){
   var myid = pdiv.id;
   var otherid = myid.replace("country_menu_report_", "menu_pol_");
   var otherdiv = document.getElementById(otherid);
   var toggle = otherdiv.style.display == "none";
   if(!toggle){
       pdiv.style.color = "#0000ff"; // forecolor
       pdiv.style.backgroundColor = "#ccccff"; // backcolor
      otherdiv.style.display = "none";
   }else{
       pdiv.style.color = "#000000"; // forecolor
       pdiv.style.backgroundColor = "#aaeeaa"; // backcolor
       otherdiv.style.backgroundColor = "#ccffcc"; // backcolor
       otherdiv.style.display = "block";
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="country_menu_report_a" onclick="changeColor(this)" style="user-select:none; cursor:pointer; color:#0000ff; background-color:#ccccff;" >test div A. click me</div>
<div id="menu_pol_a"style="display:none" >menu item A</div>
<div id="country_menu_report_b" onclick="changeColor(this)" style="user-select:none; cursor:pointer; color:#0000ff; background-color:#ccccff;" >test div B. click me</div>
<div id="menu_pol_b" style="display:none" >menu item B</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion I think
If you try to call the button

```
$menutext .= "<div id=\"country_menu_report_name\" onclick=\"menuShowPol('".$pol."');changeColor('".$pol."'); return false;\">".$thispol."</div>\n";
```

The function has to pick up the same button

Look at the function that your looking for an element with the id:

```
document.getElementById('menu_pol_div'+pdiv).style.display = "inline-block";
```

You Need look same id in this line:

```
document.getElementById('country_menu_report_name\')
```

or
    $menutext .= "".$thispol."\n";

and look the "pvid" is in the ID: example

for

```
$menutext .= "<div id=\"country_menu_report_name\" onclick=\"menuShowPol('".$pol."');changeColor('".$pol."'); return false;\">".$thispol."</div>\n";
```

you can use:

```
pvid = "report_name\"
document.getElementById('country_menu_'+pvid)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have two css classes:

```
.read{
   color: red;
}

.unread {
   color: blue;
}
```

Then, I would do something like this:

```
function changeColor(pdiv){
    //get all divs and remove read class.
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('read');
    for(var div in divs){
        div.classList.remove('read');
    }
    //add read class to current div.
    pdiv.classList.add('read');
}
```